# refresh jqueryval when updating model data annotation:mvc asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with c#, asp.net, MVC and code first entity framework.

I had a field with max legth 1024, in my model:

```
    public class MyClass
{   //other fields
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
}
```

I decided to change the max length from 1024 to 3000

```
     public class MyClass
{   //other fields
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
}
```

I also created a migration using entity framework code first(my database is updated, since I used update-database)>

```
 AlterColumn("dbo.Paper", "Abstract", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 3000));
```

But when I run my application, I receive an error from my front end

[image: problem]

what do you think is causing the validation problem?thanks

**update**
I cleaned and rebuild the solution but the same error message is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the solution and rebuild it.

Hope it will be working.

Comment: thanks, I tried it but for some reason I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: please let me know your EF version.